# Change python turtle size

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I a having trouble with the Turtle module in Python 
an error keeps occurring
`Turtle' object has no attribute 'shapesize`
I want to change the size of my Turtle sprite

This is my code

```
import turtle
my_turtle = turtle.Turtle()
my_turtle.shapesize(1)
```

I am using repl.com as my IDE

Does anyone know why this isn't working?

Comment: The code is fine, you might want to run it locally and not on an online IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repl.com supplies their own turtle.py library that isn't the one that comes with Python.  This library has half the symbols of the standard one and does not include `shapesize` nor it's synonym `turtlesize`.

Available symbols and aliases include:

```
['Screen', 'Turtle', 'back', 'backward', 'begin_fill', 'bk', 'bye', 'circle',
'clear', 'clone', 'color', 'degrees', 'delay', 'distance', 'done', 'dot', 'down',
'end_fill', 'fd', 'fill', 'fillcolor', 'forward', 'getpen', 'getscreen',
'getturtle', 'goto', 'heading', 'hideturtle', 'home', 'ht', 'isdown',
'isvisible', 'left', 'lt', 'mainloop', 'onclick', 'ondrag', 'onrelease', 'pd',
'pencolor', 'pendown', 'pensize', 'penup', 'pos', 'position', 'pu', 'radians',
'reset', 'right', 'rt', 'seth', 'setheading', 'setpos', 'setposition',
'setundobuffer', 'setx', 'sety', 'shape', 'showturtle', 'speed', 'st', 'stamp',
'towards', 'tracer', 'undo', 'undobufferentries', 'up', 'update', 'width',
'window_height', 'window_width', 'write', 'xcor', 'ycor']
```

Missing symbols and aliases include:

```
['Canvas', 'Pen', 'RawPen', 'RawTurtle', 'ScrolledCanvas', 'Shape',
'TurtleScreen', 'Vec2D', 'addshape', 'begin_poly', 'bgcolor', 'bgpic',
'clearscreen', 'clearstamp', 'clearstamps', 'colormode', 'end_poly',
'exitonclick', 'filling', 'get_poly', 'get_shapepoly', 'getcanvas', 'getshapes',
'listen', 'mode', 'numinput', 'onkey', 'onkeypress', 'onkeyrelease',
'onscreenclick', 'ontimer', 'pen', 'register_shape', 'resetscreen',
'resizemode', 'screensize', 'settiltangle', 'setup', 'setworldcoordinates',
'shapesize', 'shapetransform', 'shearfactor', 'textinput', 'tilt',
'tiltangle', 'title', 'turtles', 'turtlesize']
```

Comment: thankyou. Is there any way I could import these or would I have to use another IDE?